# problem writing array results to a csv file

Tags: php, arrays, fwrite

I have a csv file I need to cleanup.  It contains 13 fields, but I only need 7 (Business, Address, City, St, Zip, Phone, Email)

I need to run through all of the records and create a new output of just the records with email addresses.

In  nutshell... I load the original file, run the for loop, explode the results, then look for   the records where the $tmp[10] index is not null.  I then get the rest of the rest of required fields, and do a foreach loop and fwrite the results to a new csv file.

Depending on how I tweak the code, I get either... 
A text file of just email addresses.
or
A text file of just the last record with an email address.

I have been working on this too long and I just need a fresh set of eyes to point out the problem.  I am new to php, and want to make this work.  Thanks on advance.

```
    <?php
    // See if file exists and is readable
    $file = 'uploads/AK_Accountants.csv';
    $newfile = basename($file,".csv");
    $newfile = $newfile.Date("Ymd").".csw";
    $fileNew = fopen('uploads/AK_'.Date("Ymd").'.csv','w+');
    // Read the file into an array called $sourcefile
    $sourcefile = file($file);
    // Loop through the array and process each line
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($sourcefile); $i++) {
        // Separate each element and store in a temp array
       $tmp = explode('","', $sourcefile[$i]);
        // Assign each element of the temp array to a named array key
        if ($tmp[10] != "") {
            $sourcefile[$i] = array('Business_Name' => $tmp[1], 'Address' => $tmp[3], 'City' =>  $tmp[4], 'State' => $tmp[5], 'Zip' => $tmp[6], 'Phone' => $tmp[7], 'Email' => $tmp[10]);
            foreach($sourcefile[$i] as $key => $value);
                fwrite($fileNew, $value);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You say you've been working on this code a long time but actually this code is from page 187 of *PHP solutions, dynamic web design made easy* by David Powers and you haven't really added much to it at all. ;)

Comment: Your suggestion helped.  Thank you

Comment: This is the comment section. Answers are below. To comment on an answer, click the `add comment` link directly below the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a quick glance:

```
foreach($sourcefile[$i] as $key => $value);
    fwrite($fileNew, $value);
```

should be

```
foreach($sourcefile[$i] as $key => $value){
    fwrite($fileNew, $value);
}
```

Also, you have

```
$newfile = $newfile.Date("Ymd").".csw";
```

rather than what I assume should be

```
$newfile = $newfile.Date("Ymd").".csv";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last foreach statement is terminated by a ';' and has no code block.  Once the foreach statement has finished iterating you'll get the last value written to file i.e. just the email address.

You currently have

```
foreach (... ) ;
fwrite(...);.
```

but you probably mean

```
foreach( ... ) {
    fwrite(...) ;
}
```

Been there, done that :)

HTH